# Passing template function to another function which takes typedef argument

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I am trying to pass a template function to another function which takes a typedef argument.

For example, I have the function

In header.h

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class header: public baseHeader<A, B>{
public:
    typedef void (* funcPointer)(void);
    // and more...
}
```

In source.cxx

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void dosomething(void *arg){
    // code here
}

void processDoSomething(funcPointer F){
    // code here
}

template<typename A, typename B>
void work(){
    processDoSomething(dosomething);
}
```

Sorry about the code being very messy, but what I am trying to do is pass a template function to another function which takes a typedef argument. I am getting "unresolved overloaded function type" error at processDoSomething(dosomething), saying it doesn't match with the typdef argument.

I don't have much experience in template functions, so I'm not sure what is wrong.
Can someone help me?

Comment: funcPointer is defined in header class, so you need to prefix it with something in your processDoSomething function. As it doesn't depend on the template arguements, can you move the typedef outside of the class?

Comment: Yes I can but what do you mean by prefix it with something?

Comment: `header<A, B>::funcPointer F` or something

Answer (score 1):

you have defined a function pointer that accept void argument but your `dosomething` has a `void*` argument.
also i think you must declare your `processDoSomething` function like this:

```
void processDoSomething(header<someType, someType>::funcPointer F){
    // code here
}
```

**Edit:**
also because your `dosomething` is template you must use it like: (I am not sure, excuse me i can't test it with code now)

```
processDoSomething(&dosomething<someType, someType>);
```